# Overlapping questions on the topic of screen tech and G-d's name

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

There are a few overlapping questions on the topic of [screen technology and G-d's name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btechnology%5D%20name%20is:q), vis a vis "virtually" erasing the Holy name of G-d.

[Deleting files containing G-d's Name / taking the host device into the bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1186/5)
[What are the practical limits of shaimos in the common era?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10777/5)
[Is it permissible to erase the name of G-d from an E-reader?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7275/5)

and even
[When blogging/emailing/etc., do I use "God" or "G-d"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83/5)

I'm not sure which to mark as a dupe of which (some have been marked, but some haven't).  There are also similar, semi-related questions about using this technology to "write/erase" on Shabbath.  In addition, incorporate elements of others without being perfect dupes.

Can anyone come up with a way to dupe/merge them so that the overlaps are effectively dealt with, but the stand-alone elements are able to be their own questions?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, better?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see….

- [When blogging/emailing/etc., do I use "God" or "G-d"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83) asks just "Is there a religious problem with typing out the name: 'G-o-d'?".
- [Deleting files containing G-d's Name / taking the host device into the bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1186) asks about God's name in a file (not visible): deleting such a file or bringing it into a bathroom. So do [What are the practical limits of shaimos in the common era?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10777) and [Downloading Torah in the bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18397), both closed as duplicates of it, as they should be.
- [Is it permissible to erase the name of G-d from an E-reader?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7275) asks *according to the view that clearing a name from a screen is okay* whether the same would apply to a more paper-like screen (a Nook e.g.).
- [Does closing a browser with His name count as a sin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16061), closed as duplicate of several others, asks whether one can remove God's name from a screen by closing a window.
- [G-d's name on screen readers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31715) asks whether one can speak the Tetragrammaton using a screen reader.

I think [When blogging/emailing/etc., do I use "God" or "G-d"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83) is very broad — more "let's cover all aspects of this practical question" than "let's analyze this halachic concept". (The other questions are farther along the spectrum toward the latter.) That's how the answers took it, also. I don't think we should close any of the others as a duplicate of [When blogging/emailing/etc., do I use "God" or "G-d"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83), since they are more pointed; on the other hand, [When blogging/emailing/etc., do I use "God" or "G-d"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83) itself asks about something the others don't address (English names), and the answers address that point, so it cannot be closed as a duplicate, either. ([Why do people say "God" in English and not "Gosh"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16511) addresses English names, but only with respect to speaking.)

So none of the open questions should be closed in my opinion. I wish there were something we could do about [When blogging/emailing/etc., do I use "God" or "G-d"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83) — re-ask the parts of it that are not duplicates of existing open questions (or of [Does closing a browser with His name count as a sin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16061)) and then close it perhaps — but I can't think of a way to do that that doesn't lose the existing answers, alas.

[Does closing a browser with His name count as a sin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16061), closed, asks about removing a name from a screen, which none of the open questions ask about, so should be reopened.

I do think that linking each question to every other related question in the text of the question itself would be valuable.

Comment: This answer doesn't (or, at least, doesn't yet) deal with the "similar, semi-related questions about using this technology to 'write/erase' on Shabbath" mentioned in the question above.

Comment: I think that subject is distinct enough to stand on its own, and I haven't really looked at them carefully enough to opine as to whether they overlap too much with each other. I just mentioned it as a tangentially related topic. Maybe if these are good enough to stand on their own, we should create a new tag for virtual writing?